# Deployment as a single promise syntax

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration

Naive question: (Background - just started studying truffle framework) - in one place it mentions "it is possible to write your deployment as a single promise chain if you find that syntax to be more clear" - can some one give me an example of that? Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you would link to where you read that.

Comment: @smarx here is the link http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the botton of your link there's an example how to chain promises in javascript.

```
module.exports = (deployer, network) => {
  deployer.then(() => {
    return deployer.deploy(ContractA, param1, param2);
  }).then(() => {
    return deployer.deploy(ContractB, anotherparam);
  }).then(() => {
    const instanceA = ContractA.at(ContractA.address);
    return instanceA.methodInContractA(ContractB.address);
  }).then(() => {
    const instanceB = ContractB.at(ContractB.address);
    return instanceB.anotherMethodInContractB(ContractA.address, anotherparam2);
  });
}
```